# Facebook Sharer, how to specify image without meta tags? is it possible to specify this in google play console?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Im creating a button for users to share my android app, so im doing it simple with facebook sharer link but I read that I cant no more pass the image url as a parameter in sharer.php, so I was wondering if theres another way to choose the image that appears, the url is play.google.com so I cant specify any meta tags.

Well I think the answer is no, but I though maybe in google developer console I could some how specify the image that should pop when sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Feed Dialog instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

It offers a "picture" parameter.